# Building associations in a before-filter in rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am migrating an app from rails3.2.13 to rails4.0.0-rc1. I am having the following code:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars
  before_create :build_bars

  private

  def build_bars
    self.bars.build({name: 'Bar 1'})
    self.bars.build({name: 'Bar 2'})
  end
end
```

The code above worked in rails3, but creates empty records in rails4. Some try & error in the console revealed that, indeed, attributes are not assigned.

```
f = Foo.new
f.bars.build({name: 'Bar'})
 => #<Bar id: nil, name: nil>
```

What's the proper way to build associations and have them being saved together with its parent record?

Comment: This may have something to do with `attr_accessible` being replaced with strong parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think that @Mischa is right. i've been migrating my app over to rails4 and it works:

```
user.authorizations.build provider: "bla"
=> #<Authorization id: nil, provider: "bla", uid: nil, user_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

you can have a look at the changes i did: https://github.com/phoet/on_ruby/pull/83/files#L23L59

most probably it's removing:

```
# Mass assignment settings
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true
```

Comment: nice hint, but I removed that part when migrating.

Comment: @pduersteler are you still using attr_accessible with a backwards compatible gem?

Comment: nope, no backwards-compatibility gem and no `attr_*` defined (expect accessors). If i define e.g. attr_accessible, I get an error.

Comment: nothing at all.. I think I am going to generate a clean rails4 skeleton and move over all the app-related code.

Comment: did you try running rake rails:upgrade ?

Comment: there is no such task displayed by `rake -T`

Comment: Marking your answer as accepte because it helped a lot, but basically the error was because of my `method_missing`. However, I didn't mentioned that in the code so nobody could've found that out ;)